# Why Object's properties get undefined when pass through as paramters

Tags: jquery, json, rest

Why passing parameter in this JavaScript method makes it's attributes undefined, this is what I am trying at the moment,

```
    $.each(data.GetSomeRestMethodResult, function (index, item) {
            $("#sTable").append(AnotherMethods(item.a, item.b, item.c));
        });

    function AnotherMethods(a, b, c) {
        alert(a +" - "+ b +" - "+ c);
        var r = "<tr class='Row' onclick='LoadDetails(" + a + b + c ")'></tr>"
    }
```

Now if I use chrome Sources and debug, item has all values but when i look at parameters within sub function they are all undefined :(

**Edit**

Fixed the issue, as WCF web services was sending array of a specific type of object (I changed it myself but forgot to update JS) however below is what worked for me,

```
    $.each(data.GetSomeRestMethodResult.TYPEOFOBJECT, function (index, item) {
            $("#sTable").append(AnotherMethods(item.a, item.b, item.c));
        });

    function AnotherMethods(a, b, c) {
        alert(a +" - "+ b +" - "+ c);
        var r = "<tr class='Row' onclick='LoadDetails(" + a + b + c ")'></tr>"
    }
```

Above code is hand written, sorry I couldn't post all code as it was just too much @ webservices, full js file etc.

Comment: It doesn't. Post a [minimal, complete example demonstrating the problem you're having](http://sscce.org). The above will work just fine. If `item` really has the properties `a`, `b`, and `c`, the values of them will be passed into `AnotherMethods`. (Side note: You're using the return value of `AnotherMethods`, but it doesn't return anything.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, going to change the code and post it as soon as possible now

Comment: @yaron please consider learning more about the jQueri API. That `onclick` probably shouldn't be there (use .click instead) - Also, you probably don't want to mix your data and your presentation.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks for the advise, will implement it in my code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Updated based on your update)*

The problem is that you're using the return value of `AnotherMethods` (passing the return value into `append`), but `AnotherMethods` doesn't actually return anything. It just creates a variable, `r`. You also have a syntax error (a missing `+` after `c`).

This works, for instance:

```
$.each(data.GetSomeRestMethodResult, function (index, item) {
  $("#sTable").append(AnotherMethods(item.a, item.b, item.c));
});

function AnotherMethods(a, b, c) {
  return "<tr class='Row' onclick='LoadDetails(" + a + b + c + ")'><td>Row for " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + "</td></tr>";
}
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/cihat/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/cihat/2/edit)

Comment: This actually looks pretty close to the actual problem. Look at the update (he wants to return an `r` variable).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Thanks for pointing out that the Q was updated. Yes, you're right, still not returning anything (and a syntax error). Updated the answer.